# SignTool not found while having .NET resources installed. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, .net

I have installed:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack

However, I get the following exception message:
"SignTool.exe not found"

when calling this method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126008(v=vs.121).aspx

Am I missing something? Should I install something in addition?

Comment: It is a Windows SDK tool, default install location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool.exe for SDK v8.1.  Trying to avoid paying for a VS license or the free Express edition gets to be unproductive when you get stuck like this :)

Comment: Grab a tool like [Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) to make sure it's not just a path issue.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I checked the path and I do have signtool.exe .I can find it myself. I just need to make sure that the method I referred to can also find it. Still no success.

Comment: @ashes999: I can not configure the path as far as I know. It is a standard .NET method that should "just work" when the SDK is installed. The problem is that it does not work on my machine.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thank you for that comment. I had the same problem finding where signtool.exe was. +1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll need to install .Net 2.0.  The URL you reference states in remarks:

> This overload of the method calls SignTool.exe and therefore requires
>   the .NET Framework 2.0 to be installed.

Comment: I do have .NET 2.0 on my machine (however I do not see it in the programs list). I use XML Notepad 2007 (which is based on .NET 2.0)  http://xmlnotepad.codeplex.com/ . Moreover, In C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework (and Framework64) there are 2.0 folders available. I can target this framework in VS 2013 as well. So I already have it.